# Error when using JQueryUI with TypeScript and DefinitelyTyped definition file

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, typescript, npm, definitelytyped

So I'm trying to use JQueryUI with TypeScript and so far I've installed JQueryUI with `npm install jquery-ui-dist` and JQuery with `npm install jquery`. I've also added the definition files from DefinitelyTyped with `npm install --save-dev @types/jquery` and `npm install --save-dev @types/jquery-ui`.

I've got the following file (some parts omitted):

```
///<reference path="../../node_modules/@types/jqueryui/index.d.ts"/>
import * as $ from "jquery";
import "jquery-ui";

export default class Resizer {

    public static extraMargin = 5;

    public static setVerticalResizer(...) {
        ...
        let topElem: HTMLElement = <HTMLElement> cardElem.querySelector(".my-class");

        $(topElem).resizable({
            ...
        });
    }
}
```

And upon building and running I get the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: r(...).resizable is not a function`

So I guess there's some problem with my way of importing JQueryUI? Or maybe JQueryUI was not installed correctly? Although the import and definitions seem to be working correctly in VS Code.

This is also how I'm using them in the HTML file:

```
<script src="node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.mis.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.min.css">
```

Any ideas on how to solve the problem and use JQueryUI with TypeScript?

Comment: try to import `jquery-ui` using `import "jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui";` and let me know what happening. Are you using webpack?

Comment: @Diullei thank you for your comment but it seems to throw the same error: `Uncaught TypeError: n(...).resizable is not a function`

Comment: Remove the script tag. This is not a TypeScript error, this is a runtime error. You are loading `jquery-ui` twice! once in the script tag `<script src="node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.mis.js"></script>
` and then again in your module with`import * as $ from "jquery";
import "jquery-ui";` The code in the module is correct, but the script tag will cause failure.

Comment: This solved it! if you make an answer with this explanation I'll mark it as the solution @AluanHaddad

Comment: @SashaFonseca glad your problem is resolved. I added my comment (slightly edited) as an answer, thank you.

Comment: I noticed you have something else in your code that is suspicious. It's not really related, but I added a note about it in the answer since it's a harmful

Comment: I have the same context but I get the "Property 'accordion' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is not a TypeScript error, this is a runtime error.

*jQueryUI* is actually being loaded twice!

Once via a script tag

```
<script src="node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.mis.js"></script>
```

and then again in your module.

```
import $ from "jquery";
import "jquery-ui";

export default class ....
```

The code in the module above *is* correct, but the script tag is causing failure.

Additionally, I see that you have

```
///<reference path="../../node_modules/@types/jqueryui/index.d.ts"/>
```

Remove this! While it won't cause a runtime issue, that construct is for use when application code itself is written using globals, not modules.

If the types are not automatically picked up, either specify

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "moduleResolution": "node"
}
```

or use (shown with tsconfig.json next to node_modules)

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": ".", // required with paths but can be something besides "."
  "paths": {
    "jquery-ui": [
      "node_modules/@types/jqueryui/index"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: see working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aqusx7ox/)

> So I guess there's some problem with my way of importing JQueryUI? Or maybe JQueryUI was not installed correctly? Although the import and definitions seem to be working correctly in VS Code.

It's a problem when compiling the typescript. The `<script>` tags aren't important for that.

When checking the `jqueryui/index.d.ts`, you could see `resizable` is defined there:

```
interface JQuery {
    ...

    resizable(): JQuery;
    resizable(methodName: 'destroy'): void;
    resizable(methodName: 'disable'): void;
    resizable(methodName: 'enable'): void;
    resizable(methodName: 'widget'): JQuery;
    resizable(methodName: string): JQuery;
    resizable(options: JQueryUI.ResizableOptions): JQuery;
    resizable(optionLiteral: string, optionName: string): any;
    resizable(optionLiteral: string, options: JQueryUI.ResizableOptions): any;
    resizable(optionLiteral: string, optionName: string, optionValue: any): JQuery;
    ... 
}
```

(See [index.d.ts on GitHub](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/7aa22525d5ceed5729cbd089814e74a8adcd8f77/types/jqueryui/index.d.ts#L1712-L1721))

> and npm install --save-dev @types/jquery-ui.

There is no [jquery-ui](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jquery-ui)? It should be [@types/jqueryui](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jqueryui)

After correctly installing the packages @/types/jquery-ui it works for me:

```
///<reference path="node_modules/@types/jqueryui/index.d.ts"/>

export default class Resizer {

    public static extraMargin = 5;

    public static setVerticalResizer() {

        var cardElem;
        let topElem: HTMLElement = <HTMLElement> cardElem.querySelector(".my-class");

        $(topElem).resizable({

        });
    }
}
```

In VS code:

[image]

Also from commandline, no errors and a javascript file is created (running from Powershell):

> & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\2.1\tsc.exe" .\test.ts

If is still not working, please share your tsconfig.json (if you have one) and the code and command how it doesn't compile

Comment: Hello Julian, thank you for your reply but it still does not work. I've correctly installed the `@types/jqueryui` package. I've confirmed I can find the `interface JQuery` with the `resizable` stuff like you shown. VSCode also shows the suggestions and autocompletion like you shown.

Comment: Here's my tsconfig.json

       "sourceMap": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "isolatedModules": false,
        "jsx": "react",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "noLib": false,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": false,
        "noUnusedLocals": true
    }
}

Comment: https://github.com/remojansen/ts-vscode-boilerplate this is the boiler plate I'm using. I'm also building with `gulp build`

Comment: do you use some kind of module loader?

Comment: could you also include the calling script? Please edit your original post

Comment: I think for including you don't need the `export default`. It depends on the module loader you are using.