# Load jQuery and jQueryUI in Typescript error

Tags: jquery, typescript, jquery-ui

I am trying to load jquery and jqueryUI from CDN in my typescript file, I have added typings for both

`npm install --save @types/jquery@2
 npm install --save @types/jqueryui`

config.json look like this

[image]

In my type script file, I am trying to reference them with these lines

```
import * as $ from 'jquery'
import * as ui from 'jqueryui'
```

jquery is loading fine but jqueryUi is giving error

[image]

i can also see that both typings have been installed successfully

[image]

How can I fix this issue?
here is my tsconfig.json
[image]

Comment: You are importing it incorrectly. You may find this instructive: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43323515/error-when-using-jqueryui-with-typescript-and-definitelytyped-definition-file/43442870#43442870

Comment: declare $:any; for jquery in your typescript file

Comment: getting error after import * as $:any from 'jquery'; "any only refers to a type but it is being used as value"

Comment: @aluan that solution installing jquery and jqueryUi as packages but in my case I don't want to install any package and want to refer from CDN.

Comment: any help please..